# Java jframe increase look and feel (flat look)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, look-and-feel

i'm new to JAVA and i need to know how can i design my jframe like this.this look is when i creating my java project

[image]

and this look is after run the programe,

[image]

how can i create my java jframe looks like flat look,like this ...

[image]

how you are increase your java application more beautiful :)

Comment: Look into the PLAF. See [How to Set the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) for details.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks dear

Answer (score 0):

There is a few things to do to get your frame looking as close as possible to the show one, ill bullet point each step and post examples below

- First for the color background, you are going to need to do this for the outside panel (the one holding the login label and the username/password panel) and then also the username/password panel.
- Second you are going to need to add borders to both panels, for the first one you are just going to need to add a simple line border and set the color to white. For the second inner panel, it looks like you already have an etched border but you want to change that to createTitleBorder where you can state the border you wish to choose and the title which will be "Login"
- Next you are going to want to set the text to white, do this by changing your JLabels text to white using JLabel.setForegroundColor.
- Lastly you want to change the textbox background color to dark blue using JTextField.setBackground(//blue color).

### Code Example

```
//BackgroundColor
myLabel.setBackgroundColor(//your color);

//Border one
myPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.White));

//Border two
myPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitleBorder(//your border choice, "Login");

//Set text color
myLabel.setForegroundColor(Color.White);

//Change textbox background color
myTextBox.setBackground(//blueColor);
```

Hope this helps, if you have an issues just ask.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and ,its really helped to me :)
i searched this problem in the internet and someone said use libraries to increase look and feel :) how can i do this,and someone said change nimbus to windows look,how can i do this,can you give me sample :)